# How to replace value in a JSON file?

Tags: python, json

What I am trying to do is:

```
with open ('gw.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

    new_gw = {
      'gw_id': f"{react.id}",
      'gw_prize': prize,
      'gw_status': "ongoing"
    }

  data.append(new_gw)

  with open('gw.json', 'w') as j:
    json.dump(data, j, indent=4)

  #some other stuff

  #when completed

  with open ('gw.json', 'r') as jsonFile:
    data = json.load(jsonFile)
    for x in data:
      if x['gw_id'] == f"{msgid}":
        x['gw_status'] = x['gw_status'].replace('ongoing', x['completed']) #change the value of 'gw_status' when completed
    with open ('gw.json', 'w') as jsonFile:
      json.dump(data, jsonFile)
```

What I want to do is

```
[
    {
        "gw_id": "id",
        "gw_prize": "prize",
        "gw_status": "ongoing"
    }
{
        "gw_id": "904905768149590086",
        "gw_prize": "tdd",
        "gw_status": "ongoing" <== this one to be changed to "completed"
    }
]
```

but the code I wrote doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
x['gw_status'] = x['gw_status'].replace('ongoing', x['completed'])
```

with

```
x['gw_status'] = 'completed'
```

after changing this Your code will look like

```
with open ('gw.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

    new_gw = {
      'gw_id': f"{react_id}",
      'gw_prize': prize,
      'gw_status': "ongoing"
    }

    data.append(new_gw)

    with open('gw.json', 'w') as j:
      json.dump(data, j, indent=4)

    #some other stuff

    #when completed

    with open ('gw.json', 'r') as jsonFile:
      data = json.load(jsonFile)
      for x in data:
        if x['gw_id'] == f"{msgid}":
          x['gw_status'] = 'completed' #change the value of 'gw_status' when completed
      with open ('gw.json', 'w') as jsonFile:
        json.dump(data, jsonFile)
```

**gw.json** file before running the code

```
[
  { "gw_id": "id", 
    "gw_prize": "prize", 
    "gw_status": "ongoing" 
    }
]
```

**gw.json** file after running the code

```
[
  { "gw_id": "id", 
    "gw_prize": "prize", 
    "gw_status": "ongoing" 
    },
  {
    "gw_id": "904905768149590086",
    "gw_prize": "tdd",
    "gw_status": "completed"
  }
]
```

Comment: I have added full code check it now it may be helpful for you.

Comment: Can you tell me the exact problem which you are facing.
What output are you getting or error (if any)

Comment: it didn't worked . only thing it did. is make everything in one line in the file 'gw.json'

Comment: there is no error

Comment: yes its making everything in one line but after adding a new gw to the end of that array.

Comment: nope it does nothing other then that. let me show you

Comment: gw.json from this https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV2J1.png to this https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYGvm.png the code :- https://i.imgur.com/UyEckkv.png

Comment: its not data.x['gw_status'] = 'completed'
just use x['gw_status'] = 'completed'

Comment: no no i tried that just now. before that i tried. i just tried to because x[] didn't worked

Comment: print and check if your msgid matches x['gw_id']

Comment: i checked and i forgot to add a .id after. msg.id
it should have been if x['gw_id'] == f"{msgid.id}":
i am really sorry i wasted your time.
now it worked thanks! but can i prevent it all to go in one line?
again i am really sorry i wasted your time